# Why does this display 10 WordPress items instead of five?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the code working but instead of displaying the 5 most recent items it displays 10.

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'posts-per-page' => 5,
        'cat'      => 11,
        'order'    => 'DESC'
    );
    query_posts( $args );
    if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            echo "<li><a href='" . get_permalink() . "' class='post-wrap'>
                <span class='post-loop-image'>";
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "<img src='http://i0.wp.com/hanahanpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/unknown_person.png?fit=1200%2C1200' alt='default' />";
                    }
                echo "</span>";
            echo "<span class='wanted'>";
            the_title();
            echo "</span></span></a></li>" ;
         endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
...See all Wanted   

</ul>

</div>
```

It is probably something simple that I am missing but I am at a lost. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Do you have Sticky Posts? Does adding `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` to your array fix the issue?

Comment: Added that in and it still displays 10. Good idea though.

Comment: What happens if you change 5 to... lets say 4? Does it display 8 posts or still 10 posts?

Comment: I just tried changing it to 4 and '4'. Both still displayed ten recent posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually with the code. Instead of using

```
'posts-per-page' => 10,
```

And it should have been

```
'posts_per_page' => 10,
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the WP documentation:

> Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As
>   explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
>   the main query. Double Note: query_posts() is overly simplistic and
>   problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with
>   new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and
>   will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when
>   dealing with posts pagination). Any modern WP code should use more
>   reliable methods, like making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this
>   purpose. TL;DR don't use query_posts() ever;

Use WP_Query instead, for example:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'cat'      => 11,
    'order'    => 'DESC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
.....
```

Comment: I tried this using this code, http://pastebin.com/VdxTtrEM but it still displays 10 posts and now it displays all posts instead of using the ones from the specific category.

Comment: `'posts-per-page'` should be `'posts_per_page'`